# I already installed @react-navigation/stack but i got error: Error: Unable to resolve module `@react-navigation/stack` from `App.js`:

Tags: react-native

I already installed @react-navigation/stack but again I got "error: Error: Unable to resolve module `@react-navigation/stack` from `App.js`: @react-navigation/stack could not be found within the project."

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.3",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.3.11",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.3.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.0",
    "native-base": "^2.15.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.7.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.16.1",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.15.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.3",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.6.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.2",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.10.1"
  },
```

Please help

Comment: Try restarting packger server by running `react-native run-ios` or `react-native run-android` or just a `react-native start`

Answer (score 1):

you installed `react-navigation-stack` instead of `@react-navigation/stack`

run

```
npm i --save @react-navigation/stack
```

Answer (score 0):

I remove the react-native/stack which I installed previously.

And I Installed

`npm install --save @react-navigation/stack`

This is worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You did not install the @react-navigation/stack package,
I cant see the @react-navigation/stack package installed in your dependencies.

just type `npm i --save @react-navigation/stack`